# Cannot create Windows Service for MySQL (Vista)

Tags: mysql

I uninstalled MySQL 5.1 from Vista as I lost the username/password, however I forgot to stop the MySQL service before doing so. Now whenever I try to reinstall it I get to the final configuration screen which then fails with the message "Cannot create Windows Service for MySQL Error:0".

I've uninstalled MySQL and removed all related files/folders/registry entries but still no joy...

Does anyone know a way to resolve this as I can't seem to find a fix online anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Services manager (`Start` -> `services.msc`) and scroll down to see if there's an entry for MySQL available.  If so, double-click on it.  Look for an entry at the top of the `General` Tab called `Service name`.  Make a note of what that name is.

Now open up an elevated Command Prompt. (`Start` -> `Command Prompt`, then right-click and Open as Administrator)  Run the command: `sc delete service_name`, where `service_name` is the service name from the Service manager is the previous paragraph.

That should take care of it for you.

Edit: There are keys in the registry that correspond to this under `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services`, but the entries under that key are restricted to SYSTEM access only by default under Vista.  Mucking around in there can easily break a system.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the MySQL service described by [@afrazier](https://serverfault.com/questions/135527/cannot-create-windows-service-for-mysql-vista/135531#135531) was nowhere to be found however I nanaged to resolve this with some further digging.

It turns out that a hidden folder "ProgramData" on the root of my C: drive held a MySQL folder also. Removing this then allowed me to install/start the service without error.